# Haskell, profiling memory usage of imported library

Tags: haskell, profiling

I am trying to understand the memory usage of a Haskell program, and I suspect that lot of the memory allocation is happening in an external library I am importing. I am aware of the `-prof` option to GHC, but this gives me only a breakdown for my own code. I would like to extend this to the imported library to learn how I can modify my use of this library or the library itself to reduce memory use. This is an open-source library that I have installed using `cabal`.

What is the easiest way to set up things so that I can profile the library itself?

Comment: This old issue on Cabal's GitHub https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/193 which references this mailing list post http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/cabal-devel/2007-January/000379.html seems to be relevant.

Answer (score 5):

You need to install the library with profiling enabled:

```
cabal install very-cool-library --reinstall --enable-library-profiling
```

After that, you should also see the library functions in your profile.